# Adding title to NavigationBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have two different view controllers added to the view controllers array of a TabBarController and this TabBarController is added to a Navigation Controller.

Now I want to show different title for different views in the tabbar, on the navigationController.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the title within the navigation bar is taken from the navigation item from it's top view controller.  It sounds like its top view controller, in your case, is the tab bar controller, so you'll want to set the title of the tab bar controller whenever the tab bar changes.

Specifically, you'll want to assign a `UITabBarControllerDelegate` to the tab bar controller's `delegate` property and implement the following method:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    tabBarController.title = viewController.title;
}
```

The line is equivalent to

```
    tabBarController.navigationItem.title = viewController.navigationItem.title;
```

So you can use either one.  Any way, set the titles of the individual tab view controllers to whatever title you want, and then the title will change when the tabs change.

Comment: no i want to change the navigationcontroller title whenever the tab bar changes... how can i do that...

Comment: thanks Ed... with some changes to your code i could now display titles on the navigationcontroller....

Comment: Ed..In the above application ..how can i add a done button to the navigation bar from one of the view .... i tried many ways .. like

self.navigationItem.rightBarButton = self.doneButton;

but this is not working

Comment: Perhaps you should ask a new question for this.  However assuming you mean self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem, and self.doneButton is a non-null reference to a UIBarButtonItem, how does it not work?

Comment: Ed.... thanks for ur reply...
I used
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.doneButton 

and it worked....but i dont know why it didnt work the other way... 
do u have any idea...?. can u pls explain me as i am new to iphone app development..

Comment: I couldn't tell you exactly what the problem is, but my first gues is that self is not the topviewcontrollerr when that line gets called.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have three viewcontrollers having three different view and you want to change the title of navigation bar,when you are pushing secondViewcontroller and same when you are thirdviewcontroller then:

```
viewController2.navigationItem.title = @"Select Template";
viewController3.navigationItem.title = @"Template";
```

This way we can change the title of navigation bar while pushing some next view controller.

Hope it helps.